# Mysql Database design - capturing video usage metrics

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I recently got handed over this existing application. There is a mysql database table which is being used for tracking the time till where the user has last watched the video.

The simplistic bare version of the table is

```
id -> Primary_key
user_id
video_id
last_watched_time
last_viewed_time (DateTime)
```

In the last_watched_time column, they store the time in seconds from where to start playing the video again.

The way it is done is, when the user starts playing the video, a new record is inserted in the table (if record for that user and video does not exist) and then while the user is watching the video - every 20 seconds - an update is done on that record to capture the last watched time. This is so the if the user clicks on the next video without pressing the stop button - we know the time where he stopped.

So if a user watches a new video for 1 min and closes the browser, the last_watched_time column gets updated 3 times 20,40,60. The last value stored is 60. So when he comes back - the video starts playing from the 1 min mark.

```
id  |  user_id  |  video_id  |  last_watched_time  |  last_viewed_time
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   |     10    |     6      |       60            | 2018-10-01 10:10:10
```

So this is an existing table with live data.

Now they want to start measuring detailed metrics of the users usage like 
- In last 7 days , how many hours of video the user has watched broken down by day
- In last 6 hours, how many hours of video the user has watched broken down by hour

So my first thought was to do the following
- add another column called view_time to this table
- change every 20 sec updates to insert statements

So for the same scenario above, the data in the table would be

```
id  |  user_id  |  video_id  |  last_watched_time  |  view_time  |  last_viewed_time
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   |     10    |     6      |         0           |      0      |   2018-10-01 13:10:10
2   |     10    |     6      |        20           |     20      |   2018-10-01 13:10:30
3   |     10    |     6      |        40           |     20      |   2018-10-01 13:10:50
4   |     10    |     6      |        60           |     20      |   2018-10-01 13:11:10
```

Now if the same user comes back after 2 hours, forwards the video by 10 minutes and watches for 25 seconds

```
5   |     10    |     6      |       660           |    600      |   2018-10-01 15:11:10
6   |     10    |     6      |       680           |     20      |   2018-10-01 15:11:30
```

With this, I am still tracking the last_watched_time and if they want daily or hourly metrics, I can group by day or hour and sum up the view_time to know how many minutes the user watched that day or hour.

The obvious issue I see with this approach is if the user watches video for 4 hours - going by the 20 second insert statements to capture the last_watched_time - approximately 720 rows will be inserted into this table. And if we are talking about 100 users - the number just multiplies.

Is this approach even right. How should I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Do the work on `INSERT` instead of on `SELECT`.  This way much less data needs to be stored, and the `SELECTs` are much faster.

If all you want is the aggregate watch times, then store only that.  That is, when a new record comes in, augment the existing record *if* it was 20 seconds ago.

Since you want daily and hourly watch times, whenever it is a new hour, don't add to the existing record, but start a new record.  At the extreme, this will shrink the number of rows by 180x (60 minutes @ 20-second intervals).  For 'surfing', there may be no shrinkage.

Comment: Thanks Rick - maybe my question wasn't clear. If I simply update the existing record instead of inserting - then I will not be able to compute how many hours the user watched on a particular day or how many minutes he watched in a given hour.

Comment: @Gublooo - I added to my Answer.